# What do you do when you need to ask a question but there is no site for it?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For example, pretend I am a Stack Exchanger looking to ask a question on Emoji.

I am looking to ask a question on what the main emoji font is.

What would I do since there is no Emoji site?

Comment: For a question like this, more research is probably a good first step. Emoji aren't a special font.

Comment: How about a little probe on Quora or related first?

Comment: @PolyGeo what area 51 got to do with this? This is part of a possible answer, not the question.

Comment: Not every question has a home on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest using a Google search like:

https://stackexchange.com/search?q=emoji

to see if you get any hits on Stack Exchange sites that have existing questions about Emoji.

If you do, then explore their `help/on-topic` pages to see if your question appears to fit well enough to ask it.

If you draw a blank, and are really enthusiastic about Emoji, then check [Area 51](//area51.stackexchange.com/) to see if there may be an existing proposal that will help you in the future, and if there is not, then consider proposing one.

However, not every question is suitable for Stack Exchange.

Comment: _"not every question is suitable for Stack Exchange"_ Signal boost.